# In the Entity Framework Code First Approach - perform Updaterange()

Tags: entity-framework

I need to perform the update operation on the List of Model Object. 
As of now I am able to update while looping through them.

```
*public virtual void UpdateList(List<TEntity> entity)
{
foreach (TEntity ent in entity)
 {
 if (Entities.Any(h=>h.Id == ent.Id))
 {
 Entities.Attach(ent);
 _context.Entry(ent).State = EntityState.Modified;
 }
 }
 }*
```

Is there any direct way I can update List without looping through them?

Comment: *without looping thru them* Why?

Comment: no, there is not. How would you modify a number of entries without looping through them? IF you do that while the entries are attached to a context with ChangeTracking enabled, you don't even have to set them to modified afterwards. If you detach them from context before adding them again... well, of course you'll have to tell EF what to do with the objects in your context, it can't just guess which one you want to insert and which to update.

Comment: Yet another "thru" and I "thru" you "thru" the window :-)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what you're looking for is bulk operations. Entity Framework isn't suited for bulk operations. As the number of changes EF has to track increases, performance degrades.

There are some possible work arounds:

1. Commit your changes on intervals as you enumerate through the list that you're updating. i.e. `SaveChanges` after you have inserted or updated 1000 more items in the context.
2. The more items that are tracked by EF, the harder EF has to work. Part of this is alleviated by option 1, but you can also disable tracking. Fair warning, there are some catches to this so be certain to read up on everything you have to account for when disabling change detection.
3. If you're process requires a massive amount of changes, you might be better off using stored procedures than EF.

Note: 1000 items in option one is an arbitrary number. If you choose to go this route, you should run tests to see what range works best for the objects that you are working with.

What you'll find is:

- a list of size `listSize`
- a number `n` between 1 and `listSize`

It's much faster to call `SaveChanges` after `n` number of items than calling `SaveChanges` after every item. If `listSize` is on the order of tens of thousands or hundreds of thousands of updates, then `n` is most likely less than `listSize`. The goal is to find the value of `n` that will allow you to update the entire list the fastest.